# Get gene annotation type from gene name

Tags: rna-seq, gene

I am having `RNA-seq` data set for `C.Elegans`. I do not know which annotation scientists used for naming the genes of it, but I need to search somehow for the `^ERCC` and `^mt-` genes like specified in the tutorial:

https://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/simpleSingleCell/

If I just implement `grepl` search for the `character` array of gene names that I have, I am always getting all values `FALSE` as if there are no `spike-in`s and mitochindrial genes.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Sample gene name from the dataset: `WBGene00023193`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you linked to does not mention ERCC or mt genes.

Before running `grepl` or any other search, you should first check your inputs. It looks like you have WormBase gene IDs if all your genes look like `WBGene00023193`. Therefore, your question is actually how to convert WormBase gene IDs to gene symbols.

Here is one potential solution: https://github.com/WormBase/website/issues/4297

After you convert, you have to make sure that you have ERCC spike-ins in your gene table (probably not) and you mitochondrial genes start with "mt-".

Comment: Sorry about that, the link was wrong. I updated it